# cPanel .htaccess is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using cPanel hosting my website, In order to hide the extension on my URL from customer to view i found using .htaccess.
But i have no idea how this .htaccess works. Here is the code ALL i have in .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteOptions inherit
```

i just copy this off other solution. and when i replace the file from public_html/ folder, it just does not work when i check the website. is there like a activating phase i miss? is it really simply just put it in the root folder and it works? i just wanted to hide .php from my URL.

`RewriteOptions inherit`

is the original code from the .htaccess on the root file. i just keep it.

Comment: Add [L] flag on rule and check mod rewrite is enabled in httpd.conf.

Comment: httpd.conf? i don't know where is that. I have to make it? or it should be in the website already?